# Captcha MVC 4 Image not Displaying

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, captcha

**Details:** I'm using a Captcha control in my MVC 4 project but I'm getting the red cross where the image should be. The strange thing is if I put this on my main page (`http://localhost/CaptchaDemo/`) it works fine, but when I put it on the page I need it (`http://localhost/CaptchaDemo/Account/Register/`), it refuses to load. F12 shows the image src as `CaptchaDemo/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t={random stuff here}`

**Question:** How can I make my Captcha image display on `http://localhost/CaptchaDemo/Account/Register/` when it works fine on `http://localhost/CaptchaDemo/` (where I don't even need it!)

Comment: It looks like the URL for the image is relative, which is only going to work if it's called from the correct relative location.  Make the URL absolute.  I'm not sure how to do that in this unspecified "Captcha control" but essentially that's what you need to do.  MVC has helpers like `@Url.Content` or `@Url.Action` to build fully-qualified URLs in your markup.

Comment: This is MVC 4 Captcha - http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know about `@Url.Content` and `@Url.Action` but I'm using a dll and when in my code I just do this: `@Html.Captcha("Generate New Image", "Input Symbols", 5, "Is required field.", false);` so I don't have anywhere to change the URL.

Comment: Interesting.  Can you confirm the client-side URLs being generated and that relative vs. absolute truly is the problem?  Admittedly I'm not familiar with this Captcha control, and a cursory look at the documentation isn't finding anything obvious.  Do the examples provided by the vendor also suffer the same issue?  If so, maybe the vendor assumes a specific usage.  If not, maybe there's a subtle difference between yours and theirs and it's worth investigating by minimally reproducing the issue in their example.

Comment: I made an example and it worked fine, but for some reason the page I'm needing it on does not like the Captcha control since it does work in the project itself. Just not calling controller when submitting and not showing images, when clicking Refresh the image is still missing and Refresh link goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Use SuperCaptcha control from codeplex.
http://supercaptcha.codeplex.com

It provides both refresh and listen features.
Easy to use and nice documentation provided. I used it in my project and it is working pretty well.